# Unity3D Keep Pinging Server Until True

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a Unity c# script designed to ping a server until a variable on the server side changes from false to true. I want a "loop function" that will ping my server every 4 seconds to check if the server side variable has changed. For some reason, I cannot figure this out (I'm new to c#). Can anyone help me setup a function that will ping a URL every four seconds and upon "Success" do something?

```
    void PendingGUI (int windowID){
        GUI.Box(new Rect(0,0,Screen.width, Screen.height), "");
        if(GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width/2 - 150, 4* Screen.height/6, 300, Screen.height/8), "Pending Mode"))
        {
            StartCoroutine("PendingMode");
            currentMenu = "PendingMode";
            Debug.Log("Pending Connection");
        }
        GUI.Label(new Rect(Screen.width/2 - 50, 32 * Screen.height/100, 200, 30), "Login Successful!");
        GUI.Label(new Rect(Screen.width/4 + 75, 32 * Screen.height/70, 300, Screen.height/8), "Click the Pending Mode Button.");
        }
    void PendingModeGUI (int windowID){
        if(PendingStatus == "disabled"){
            StartCoroutine("PingAgain");
        }
        GUI.Box(new Rect(0,0,Screen.width, Screen.height), "");
        GUI.Label(new Rect(Screen.width/4 + 150, 32 * Screen.height/70, 300, Screen.height/8), "Connection Pending...");
        }

#region CoRoutines
IEnumerator PendingMode(){
    WWWForm Ping = new WWWForm ();
    Ping.AddField ("ClassPending", "ping");
    WWW PingWWW = new WWW ("http://learn.edupal.co/login.php?action=classroom", Ping);
    yield return PingWWW;
    if (PingWWW.error != null) {
        Debug.LogError ("Cannot Connect to Server");
    } else {
        string PingReturn = PingWWW.text;
        if (PingReturn == "Success") {
            Debug.Log ("Connected to Instructor");
            PendingStatus = "enabled";
            currentMenu = "connected";
        } else {
            Debug.Log (PingReturn);
            PendingStatus = "disabled";
        }
    }
}

IEnumerator PingAgain(){
    while (PendingStatus == "disabled") {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (4);
        StartCoroutine ("PendingMode");
    }
}
#endregion
```

The issue now is that the loop will run 36 times per second and then crash the game. I created the string

```
PendingStatus = "disabled";
```

to serve as a trigger to break a while loop, but I've had no success with that either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet you're starting `PingAgain` more than once.

From your example is not clear who's calling `PendingModeGUI` but I'm assuming it's from a `OnGUI` method on some `MonoBeahviour`.

You can achieve what you want with just one Coroutine. `PendingMode` can be changed as followed:

```
IEnumerator PendingMode()
{
  while(true)
  {
    WWWForm Ping = new WWWForm ();
    Ping.AddField ("ClassPending", "ping");

    WWW PingWWW = new WWW ("http://learn.edupal.co/login.php?action=classroom", Ping);
    yield return PingWWW;

    if (PingWWW.error != null) 
    {
      Debug.LogError ("Cannot Connect to Server");
    } 
    else 
    {
      string PingReturn = PingWWW.text;
      if (PingReturn == "Success") 
      {
        Debug.Log ("Connected to Instructor");

        //stop the coroutine
        StopCoroutine("PendingMode");
      } 
      else 
      {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(4f);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note: this doesn't actually ping the server every 4 seconds, it pings the server after 4 seconds + the time to get a response.

Comment: Yes, I am using Monobehaviour. I implemented your code and it pings the server about 500 times a second. I moved StartCoroutine("PendingMode"); to void PendingModeGUI and removed the if statement. Without the StartCoroutine within PendingModeGUI, it will only fire one time and then stop.